# Is there an equivalent of Autocomplete Deluxe for Drupal 6?

Tags: 6

I saw the [Autocomplete Deluxe](http://drupal.org/project/autocomplete_deluxe) module, which has a version for Drupal 7. I am using a user reference CCK field, and I autocomplete it. I would like to reference users in the way it is done with that module: As soon as users are referenced, it should go up in some manner.

Is there an equivalent of Autocomplete Deluxe for Drupal 6?